# Mac localhost site folder permission issue

Tags: php, mysql, macos, localhost

I have a localhost set up on my *sites* folder on a mac which lets me use PHP, MySQL, phpMyAdmin and all sorts of goodies. But I have an issue when my website creates folders or files. All the permissions for _www are '**read only**.'

When I use a PHP function such as `mkdir("folder path");`, it creates folders with permission of '**read only**'. How can I configure my *sites* folder to have '**read & write**' permission for every file created or placed in *sites* folder?

Comment: Do you use default apache environment (that come with osx system)?

Comment: Yes. This is the tutorial I followed: http://machiine.com/2013/how-to-install-apache-and-php-on-a-mac-with-osx-10-8-mamp-part-1/

Comment: 1) What permission have the document root? 2) It create folders with permission 'read only' for who? for you, i suppose, or also for _www user (it would be strange). If your are able, write here the file permission (and owner/group) as they appears in Terminal, not in the Finder (i.e. `-rw-r--r--    1 _www  _www`)

Comment: So I checked the folder and got this response: drwxrwxrwx  8 USER  _www  272 15 Dec 13:19 /Users/USER/Sites
USER-***:~ USER$

Comment: When I use php mkdir, it creates folders with Me: Read&Write,  _WWW: Read Only and Everyone: Read Only

Comment: USER are you? Your problem is in Document Root or in User/Sites?

Comment: Yes, USER is me. I just want to create folders and edit folders inside my sites folder using my local php. When I create a directory, I would like to create directories inside of those directories but I can't since the created directories have permissions on them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102538/discussion-between-fusion3k-and-maciek-semik).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To activate read/write permission either for you and Apache in **global** Apache Document Root, do this in Terminal application:

```
sudo chown _www:_www /Library/WebServer/Documents
sudo chmod 0775 /Library/WebServer/Documents
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a username -t user _www
```

To activate read/write permission either for you and Apache in your **personal** Document Root, do this in Terminal application:

```
sudo chown _www:_www /Users/username/Sites
sudo chmod 0775 /Users/username/Sites
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a username -t user _www
```

**Please note:** Change `username` above with your **short** username.

By these commands, you:

1. set the owner of directory to user `_www` (Apache) of group `_www`;
2. set permissions of directory to read/write/execute to owner and group members, read/execute for others (you can type 0770 to others/none permission or 0771 to others/execute only);
3. add you to group `_www`.